# How to access remote MySql database from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, mysql, web-services

I am trying to access a remote MySql database from my iPhone application. I googled, but I can't find anything that works. Can any one suggest a clear way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the iOS SDK does not contain any API's that can access a MySQL database, you have two options:

1. Implement whatever is necessary in order to talk to a MySQL database engine.
2. Talk to an application sitting in between your iOS application and your MySQL database.

Of the two, nbr. 2 is by far the easiest, and the normal way to do that is to set up a web service somewhere that you can talk to.

You will have to implement web service methods for whatever kinds of operations you need to perform on your MySQL database.

Exactly how to talk to that web service, and exactly how to talk to the MySQL server from your web service, those are separate questions.

Comment: thanks Lasse for your answer...and where should i implement my web services in iPhone or in the server..?