# iPhone application database: MySQL & SQLite

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode, sqlite

Hi I am a student with little knowledge about iPhone application and its database.
However, I am tasked to develop an iPhone application for a company. This application must require users to do registering as member and reflecting their member points.

Currently, the company is using MySQL as their database for their current ongoing. Whereas, after the implementation of the iPhone application which database should I use?
I am aware that iPhone only supports SQLite but how can I fetch the data from their current MySQL and make a linkage so it would be centralized and not having 2 individual database?

Comment: Are you talking about storing data _on the iPhone_, or are you talking about querying a central database? It sounds to me like you're confusing these two concepts.

Comment: Yes i am confused with these two concepts. So how can i store the data? Using which database?

Comment: Note I am not an iPhone developer, and never will be... :)  BUT... I believe the iPhone only supports sqlite for data _stored on the phone_.  For data stored on a central server, where you make some sort of remote query to the database, that database can be anything at all.  It sounds like the MySQL you're talking about is a central server, and therefore whether you use sqlite, or some other storage format for data stored on the iPhone is irrelevant to whether your server uses MySQL.

Comment: @Flimzy has it right; the iPhone's Core Data internal storage system is, I believe, implemented using SQLite, but that doesn't restrict what external data stores an iPhone app can connect to. Typically, you would write a web service to sit between the app and the database anyway, so your app has no need to know what the underlying storage mechanism is.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your bosses threw you into very deep water without knowing how to swim, first.

There are a number of ways to answer your question, and I found a few related questions on various sites that might help you.

[How to access remote MySql database from iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849028/how-to-access-remote-mysql-database-from-iphone-app)

[Connecting to a remote MySQL Database](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1639731?start=0&tstart=0)

[Access mysql remote database from iPhone](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3711-access-mysql-remote-database-iphone.html)

You might want to start with just writing a small, non-database-using iPhone app to start with and then once you get the hang of it, then reach out into wild world of talking to remote databases.

hope this helps!