# Any way to access SQL server from objective c programatically

Tags: ios

can anyone tell how to access MS  SQL Server from objective c programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849028/how-to-access-remote-mysql-database-from-iphone-app

Comment: @rishi: "SQL Server" is "MS SQL" and not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no libraries for this and such scenario is very bad. You should make a web service (json preferred) using `PHP`, `ASP.NET` or whatever you can to communicate with the database...